# After using property decorator, python object has two very similar attributes (foo.bar and foo._bar). Is that ok?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, decorator

So I'm refactoring my code to be more Pythonic - specifically I've learned that using explicit getters and setters should be replaced with @property. My case is that i have an `Example` class with initialized `bar` attribute (initialization helps me to know that user set the `bar`):

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self):
    self.bar = 'initializedValue'

  @property
  def bar(self):
    return self._bar

  @bar.setter
  def bar(self, b):
    self._bar = b

  def doIfBarWasSet():
    if self.bar != 'initializedValue':
      pass
    else:
      pass
```

after running `foo = Example()` my debugger shows that foo has two attributes: `_bar` and `bar`, both set to `'initializedValue'`. Also, when I run `foo.bar = 'changedValue'` or `foo._bar = 'changedValue'`, both of them are changed to `'changedValue'`. Why there are two attributes? Isn't that redundant? I think I understand why there is `_bar` attribute - I added it in `@bar.setter`, but why there is `bar` as an string attribute? Shouldn't `bar` be rather a method leading to `bar` `@property`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine. Keep in mind that `bar` is not an *instance* attribute, but a *class* attribute. Since it has type `property`, it implements the descriptor protocol so that its behavior is different when accessed from an instance. If `e` is an instance of `Example`, then `e.bar` does not give you the instance of `property` assigned to `Example.bar`; it gives you the result of `Example.bar.__get__(e, Example)` (which in this case, happens to be `Example.bar.fget(e)`, where `fget` is the original function decorated by `@property`).

In short, every instance has its own `_bar` attribute, but access to that attribute is mediated by the class attribute `Example.bar`.

---

It's easier to see that `bar` is a class attribute if you write this minimal (and sufficient, since neither the getter nor setter in this case requires a `def` statement) definition.

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "initalizedValue"

    bar = property(lambda self: self._bar, lambda self, b: setattr(self, '_bar', b))
```

or more generally

```
def bar_getter(self):
    return self._bar


def bar_setter(self, b):
    self._bar = b


class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "initalizedValue"

    bar = property(bar_getter, bar_setter)
```